# Toggle Not Keeping The Div Displayed

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm having an issue with the div staying displayed one clicked. Here's a jsfiddle of the code that I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/UhYEB/

The screen keeps jerking on the click and then it goes right back to hiding the div.

Here's the script I'm using

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".flyopen-nav").hide();
        $("#toggle-flyout").click(function(){
            $(".flyopen-nav").toggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), also need to include the jQuery library in jsfiddle demo.

**[LIve Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UhYEB/1/)**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".flyopen-nav").hide();
        $("#toggle-flyout").click(function (event) {
            $(".flyopen-nav").toggle();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

To include jQuery library, you have to select the version of jQuery from left js framework panel as shown in picture below.

[image]